# Understanding a modified "delayed choice quantum eraser" experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

Pardon my ignorance, but I am really interested in understanding the quantum mechanics and it's interesting implications, but clearly I don't, since I keep coming up with violations to many physics theorems. In particular, the delayed choice quantum eraser experiment is of interest. Consider the wikipedia diagram,

[image]

In this experiment, there is random chance for the path that will be taken in the lower part of the diagram. Hence, one must wait till the end of the experiment and then (using the coincidence counter) filter the information of each photon's path. Hence, the patterns one sees are only known after the experiment. The Quantum entanglement is only verified after the experiment is completed.

But instead of allowing random chance, what if you forced all photons to go to a particular path. To my understanding, if PS was modified (see the following diagrams) into a switch that forced either "separate slit" detection or "interference" then would that allow "faster than light" communication?

[image]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variation of delayed choice quantum eraser](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18605/variation-of-delayed-choice-quantum-eraser)